# Why are Images repeating in Classic ASP

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript

I am currently having a problem with some thumbnail images in a classic ASP website. Essentially, I have a database in Microsoft Access that contains three tables: One with the pictures and their info, another that is linked to the pictures table and contains location information and a third table which just has some text for the website.

On the page which is coded below, each image in the database has its corresponding thumbnail printed onto the page. The user can then click on the thumbnail and be taken to the larger image with some associated information.

My problem is that the thumbnails are repeating themselves, up to 11 times.

```
<% option explicit %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Places</title>

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<!-- #include file="conn.asp" -->

<div id="container"> 

<!-- #include file="nav.asp" -->

<% dim SQL, info
'               0               1           2       3           4
SQL = "select PicturesTable.id, filename, location, title, description"&_ 
    " from PicturesTable, locationsTable"&_ 
    " where PicturesTable.locationNum = locationsTable.id"&_
    " order by locationsTable.id"


set info=conn.execute(SQL)
```

This is my loop where I think the problem is.

```
if info.eof then
  response.write "No data found."
end if
do until info.eof
  response.write "<a href=""images.asp?i=" & info(1) & """>" &_
               "<img src=""thumbs/" & info(1) & """></a>"
        info.movenext
loop


%>

</div>
<%
  conn.close
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your recordset loop code looks correct to me. Could the problem be in your SQL itself?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was in fact that I had designed the database poorly in access and I was repeating the records when they should have been unique. Hence, the repeated images. Deleting the repeated records gave me the solution. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following SQL instead; the problem is likely that you need to JOIN the two tables.

```
SQL = "SELECT PicturesTable.id, filename, location, title, description"&_ 
  " FROM PicturesTable"&_ 
  " LEFT JOIN locationsTable"&_ 
  " ON PicturesTable.locationNum = locationsTable.id"&_  
  " ORDER BY locationsTable.id
```

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM a, b WHERE a.id = b.id` does the same as an `INNER JOIN`, so that wouldn't explain repeated values in the result.